# Swift jitterclick game will not reset

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to learning swift and my jitterclick style game will not reset after it is complete. Despite already setting the isTimerRunning to false, nothing i have done seems to work. The game is supposed to begin when you press start, start a count down timer from 10, count your number of clicks, and give you a click per second score at the end. This is my first app without a tutorial and appreciate all the help i can get. Thanks

```
import UIKit

var score = 0

var timer = Timer()

var cps = score / 10

var time = 10.00

var isTimerRunning = false

var isGameComplete = true

var realTime = 0.0


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var clickingButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var CPSLabelTxt: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabelTxt: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        resetButton.isHidden = true
        resetButton.isEnabled = false
        CPSLabelTxt.isHidden = true
        scoreLabelTxt.isHidden = false
        scoreLabelTxt.text = "Press Start to begin"
    }

    @IBAction func resetButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any){
        resetButton.isEnabled = false
        startButton.isEnabled = true

        time = 10.0
        timerLabel.text = "10.00"
        isTimerRunning = false
    }


    @IBAction func clickingButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
        if !isGameComplete {
            score += 1
            scoreLabelTxt.text = "\(score)"

        }


    }

    //Start button is pressed
    @IBAction func startButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
        isGameComplete = false
        startButton.isEnabled = false

        //Count down timer begins
        if !isTimerRunning{
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            isTimerRunning = true


        }
    }

    //logic for timer
    @objc func runTimer(){

        time -= 0.01
        realTime = round(100 * time) / 100

        timerLabel.text = "\(realTime)"

        if time < 0.0 {

            isTimerRunning = false
            timerLabel.text = "0.00"

            isGameComplete = true

            resetButton.isHidden = false
            CPSLabelTxt.isHidden = false
            scoreLabelTxt.isHidden = false
            scoreLabelTxt.text = "\(score)"
            CPSLabelTxt.text = "\(cps)"

            time = -2


        }

       }
}
```

Comment: A couple of style points; there is no need for those variables to be global. Move them inside the class as properties. There is no need for the `isTimerRunning` bool; simply make `timer` an optional and set to `nil` when you invalidate then timer.  Also, decreasing a `time` counter isn't accurate; `Timer` ticks aren't accurate. Better to take a `Date` at the start and use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to determine elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

Put `timer.invalidate()` in your `resetButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any)` function. This stops the timer from running.